# Adding directive scope makes the rest non-updateable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There's a directive called `foo` which is defined like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
   {{ name }}

   <foo param="123"></foo>
</div>
```

And here's the relevant initialization fragment:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Initial name';
});

app.directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        controller : function($scope){
            $scope.name = 'Name defined in directive';
            console.log($scope.param); // undefined
        }
    };
});
```

That works as expected and overrides `Initial name` with `Name defined in directive`.

However, since there's `param` attribute I wanted to access its value. So I did one way binding like this:

```
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        controller : function($scope){
            $scope.name = 'Name defined in directive';
            console.log($scope.param); // 123 as expected
        },
        scope : {
          param : "@"
        }
    }
```

And that broke the updating of the parent scope. Now when running this, it renders `Initial name` instead of expected `Name defined in directive`. So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the scope option, you create an isolate scope which is by definition, separate from the parent scope.

You will either need to add `name` to your isolate scope and pass it in just like `param` OR you will need to remove the scope and define `param` on the parent scope.

Here's what the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) have to say about isolate scopes:

> As the name suggests, the isolate scope of the directive isolates everything except models that you've explicitly added to the scope: {} hash object. This is helpful when building reusable components because it prevents a component from changing your model state except for the models that you explicitly pass in.
>
> Note: Normally, a scope prototypically inherits from its parent. An isolated scope does not. See the "Directive Definition Object - scope" section for more information about isolate scopes.

Comment: 2-way binding on `name` won't be enough as it's a primtive type (string). It should be a property like `model.name` or use an expression binding `on-name-change="name = newName"`

Comment: 2-way binding works just fine with strings. Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mcid4CwXFoWXdxCu95ez?p=preview

Comment: Ouch, looks like you're right (even when updating the variable from withinthe directive). I don't know why I had the asumption it didn't, sorry for misleading comment then.